# Is it safe to run cryptsetup luksOpen twice?

Tags: linux, disk, luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

When I already have a LUKS block device opened using `cryptsetup luksOpen`, does invoking the command on the same machine with the same arguments including the device name for the second time just do nothing or is doing so unsafe?

Comment: have you tried doing that on a loopback device? Something very unsurprising will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to open the device with the same name, `cryptsetup` will simply tell you that the mapped device already exists. If you try different name, the call will fail because the device is in use:

```
$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 a
Device a already exists.

$ sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdc1 b
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdc1: 
Cannot use device /dev/sdc1 which is in use (already mapped or mounted).
```